# Using update_attribute and getting NoMethodError: undefined method `0=' for #<User:0x007fe470de2950

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller, update-attribute

## Problem statement

In my controller I am trying to change a boolean attribute `not_registered` in Update using `resource.update_attribute(resource.not_registered, 1)`, but am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 0= for #<User:0x007fe470de2950`.  Any idea why this is happening?  Appreciate any ideas you may have, this is the last bug I need to work out before completing this project, which will be my first in RoR!

## My progress

- I looked into using `save` instead, but can't because I need to skip validation.  Also seems inefficient since I am only updating one attribute
- In the shell, `resource` (created by Devise) appears to be an instance of the current User
- Before executing the Update controller `resource.not_registered
  => 0`, which is correct... so I know that `resource.not_registered` is correct syntax.
- If I run `resource.update_attribute`, I get `!! #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)>` ... so I know that `update_attribute` exists as a method for `resource`
- Finally, I found the documentation for update_attribute [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute).

## Code

**/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def update
        if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])        
            resource.update_attribute(resource.not_registered, "1") # this is where I get my error message
            set_flash_message :notice, :updated
            sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
            redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource)
        else
            clean_up_passwords(resource)
            render "edit"
        end     
    end

    # Code removed for brevity
end
```

**/app/models/user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
  :remember_me, :not_registered, :pay_method, :pay_desc, :email_instructions, :current_password

  def update_with_password(params={})
      # code removed for brevity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change following line

```
resource.update_attribute(resource.not_registered, "1") # this is where I get my error message
```

to

```
resource.update_attribute(:not_registered, "1") # this is where I get my error message
```

and read some solid Rails documentation. I suggest going through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html